# How can I access test methods from sub-directories

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, integration-testing

My Go project code structure looks something like this.

```
project
 |
 +-- x_test.go
 |    
 +-- sub-directory
 |  |  
 |  +-- y_test.go
```

`x_test.go` has some `struct` and methods that are used only for test purposes.

These `struct` and methods are un-accessible in `y_test.go`.
Is there a way test files can be imported in sub-directories? I cannot move the file `x_test.go` to the sub-directory as it makes use of some interfaces defined in the root level directory.

The file `y_test.go` cannot be put at the root level as it is using some instances defined in `sub-directory`, and this would cause a cyclic dependency.

Is there a way I can make the methods and struct defined in `x_test.go` visible to `y_test.go`?

Everything works fine if I don't treat `x_test.go` as a test file. i.e, I rename it to just `x.go`

Comment: _test.go files from packages other than the package being tested are not compiled, so no, you can't make this work. Define normal types and methods instead, possibly in an [internal package](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Internal_Directories).

Comment: i did try that, but I have some unexported structs being used in `x_test.go`. That was the entire reason to keep it in the root level. Moving it to an internal package causes errorss

Comment: @nikoo28 you want to share code between packages? Test code or not, the rules are simple, the code must be defined in a non-test file and it must be exported.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can make the methods and struct defined in x_test.go visible to y_test.go?

No.